# communication between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, communication

I'm making a little java game in which I would have two threads (well as the FIRST step towards multithreading...), one for the logic and one for the drawing.

So my question is: How can I make those two communicating which each other?

Requirements:

- accessing variables and object from a another thread
- syncing them so they each complete a same number of "loops" in the same time.
  (the logic calculates and then the another one draws the results and the loop begins again...)

So how is this achievable in java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well to be honest I don't really know where to start... I have trying to give the treads each other as an parameter so they would know who to refer but I haven't been able to give a thread a parameter...

Comment: Threads are the means to an end, not the end to a means. It sounds like you don't need threads at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Create a Class with logic and drawing methods. 
   Whose object is accessible by both the threads.

2. Now please do synchronize the atomic statements or methods.

3. So its like an object is shared between 2 threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy structure to use to communicate between threads is the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

I often find if you use a `BlockingQueue` it will focus you on making the threads work together correctly. For example, they will not provide the facilities you are asking for because actually those facilities are not what you want.